# Android - Maintain Presentation Display when launching another app via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, display, presentation

i have an Android application, that is basically a Restaurant Order Terminal.
It consists of an Android Terminal connected to an external display, via HDMI and USB.

I display different things on the secondary display via Presentation Class. All is working well.
My problem is when i arrive to payment:

I need to call the payment App via Intent, and listen to result via onActivityResult. Once again, it works well, but has the side effect to turn off my secondary display (as it is attached to my app) and display the payment app instead.

What i'd like to achieve : Keep displaying what i want from my app on the secondary display, while displaying the payment app on my main display.

Comment: "as it is attached to my app" -- more accurately, it is attached to your *activity*. You would have the same effect if you started another activity from the one showing the `Presentation`. In the end, `Presentation` is a subclass of `Dialog`, so it is tightly tied to the activity that displays it. If your app requires Android 8.0+, you could switch to using an activity for the secondary display. Otherwise, you will need nasty hacks (see the `PresentationService` in my `cwac-presentation` library) or to live with the behavior that you have.

Comment: Yes i meant attached to activity. Unfortunatly, my device runs on Android 7.1.1 so i can't switch to using aother activity for presentation. (Sorry i forgot to mention it). Where can i find your PresentationService? Actually my Presentation screens are Custom Fragments extending DialogFragment

Comment: Tried your Presentation Service Demo, doesn't display anything on my presentation display. Any clue why? Could you help me achieve a simple Presentation Service, with bare minimum, just to understand the way it work and then, do my own. I don't ask you to provide me with complete code, juste clues to understand how it work. Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you followed this step: "Note that using this on Android 7.1+, where a `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` window is used, requires the user to go into Settings and allow your app to draw over other apps."

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. I've got the exact same display on the two screens.Could it be related to version of Gradle i use for this project. For compatibility reasons, i need to use 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' and distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

Comment: That should not be an issue. Other than using breakpoints/logging to see what is happening in your environment, I do not have a lot of specific advice. On Android 7.1+, `PresentationService` is kind of a hack due to this window type change. 7.1 in particular is in a bad place: you cannot use the less-nasty window type, but launching activities on the external display is not supported until 8.0.

Comment: What is, basically, the concept behind your "Presentation Service"? You start a service that run on the foreground? and display a view on the Display?

Comment: `PresentationService` was a proof-of-concept for controlling the content of an external display independently from an activity. The problem with `Presentation`, as I noted earlier, is that it is a `Dialog`, and so it is tightly tied to the activity instance that displayed it. I elected to use a `Service`, as that can run completely independently from any activities that you may (or may not) have on the primary display.

Comment: However, [`PresentationService` is a small class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation/blob/v0.6.1/presentation/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/preso/PresentationService.java). You are welcome to use the code from it in some other way.

Comment: I manage to achieve what i want by Creating a class extending Service and creating a foreground  Service. Then i inflate my view and pass it to a WindowManager with my PresentationDisplay as a parameter. I think it's what your class does in some way? I still have one issue. I'd like to rotate my presentation display but can't seem to find a way on how to achieve this. As you Seem pretty aware on how Presentation work, maybe you have an idea?

Comment: There is nothing specific to the presentation stuff related to rotation that I can recall. Try rotating the actual view.

Comment: That's what i did. Rotation and Translation to fit, according to screen current resolution. Thanks for all